# Whats wrong with this (simple) firebase v2 security rule?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Allow me to explain the setup and intention before getting to the actual security rule:

1. The Firestore Database starts with a collection called 'users' at its root level.
2. The users-collection contains a single document for each (authenticated) user. The name of the document equals the user's email address, and hence the email address must be verified.
3. The user's document contains a few fields and a sub-collection called 'history' where data is stored (in a file per month).

The idea behind using the user's email address as filename is to enable cross platform (or better said cross-sign-in-method) support. For example, you could be signed in with Google on Android and with Apple on an iDevice at the same time, and as long as both accounts use the same email address, both devices share data, which is pretty elegant.

**Edit:**
The app requests the user's document and its monthly history by calling:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(_user?.email);
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(_user?.email).collection("history").doc("2021-05");
```

Now I'm trying to figure out a security rule that allows each user to access only their own data - i.e. the file that matches the user's (verified) email address. After spending some time with the docs, I came up with this simple rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email == userId && request.auth.token.email_verified == true;
    }
  }
}
```

What it's supposed to do is: To access a file: The user must be authenticated. The user's email address needs to be equal the file's name, and the email must be verified (last point is also enforced by the app).

The problem is: PERMISSION_DENIED. Do you have any ideas what's causing it?

Comment: Security Rules mean *nothing* without seeing the query you're attempting to use.  The most general point to remember is "RULES ARE NOT FILTERS" - they do NOT separate which documents might be returned for your (as yet unknown) query.  ALL the documents that meet the queries settings must ALL pass the security rule, or the ENTIRE query is DENIED.

Comment: ALSO: I HIGHLY HIGHLY HIGHLY recommend you to NOT use the email as the userId - use the uid from the authentication.  email addresses are NOT AT ALL well distributed enough to perform at at scale.

Comment: @LeadDreamer Thanks for your help! I've added the query to the question. About the email as uid: The app requires the user to verify its email address. Wouldn't it be safe to use the email address as uid if the app allows only sign-in methods that provide a verified email address? Like Google, Apple and In-App-Email/Pwd with verification logic.

Comment: The problem with the email address as documentId is NOT safety - it's efficiency.  Highly scaled systems like Firestore operate *best* when the documentID's are very well distributed, reducing contention and improving access.  Emails are by definition very organized (name@domain.tld), which is the opposite well distributed.  They are a *terrible* way to organize your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the _user.email as the documentId is not just a terrible way to Id your documents (it will be terribly inefficient at scale), it also *greatly* limits your security rules.  There is a damn good reason almost every example of the use of Auth shows using the uid as the user documentId - because said uid is available from the request.auth object directly in the security rules.

So let's change your structure, and put the email address into the user document, so you can query for it later - but use the uid from the Auth as the documentId.  I'll share how I do it, in working code:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if false;
      } // only explicit rules allowed (below)

    function aUser() {
      return request.auth.uid;
    }
    function isUser() {
      return request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    match /People/{person} {
        function thisPerson() {
            return aUser() == person;
        }
        function isPublic() {
            return resource.isPublic;
        }
        allow read: if isUser() && isPublic();
        allow read, write: if thisPerson();
        allow create: if isUser();

        match /PeopleData/{personData} { //only valid record has same id as person
            allow read, write: if thisPerson() && personData == person;
        }
    }
}
```

This is *not* all of my security rules (maybe 10%?), but it gives you an idea of the power - the uid comes from the secure access, so it's hard to spoof from the client, and requires no special set-up